# Magento: Send Custom Transactional Email in Custom Observer

Tags: email, events, magento, smtp, transactional

I'm trying send a email when admin cancel a order manually. I'm using the order_cancel_after event and my observer method run fine.

But my email is not fired. I get the following exception (above), despite all code be run.

`exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'No recipient forward path has been supplied' in /home/mydomain/www/loja/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php:309`

I tested sending a new email on my order observer: `$order->sendNewOrderEmail()`, and the new order email arrived correctly, so my SMTP is ok.

My code in observer:

```
class Spalenza_Cancelorder_Model_Observer
{
    public function enviamail(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        if ($order->getId()) {
            try {
                $translate  = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
                $email = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                $template = 16;//Mage::getModel('core/email_template') ->loadByCode('Cancelamento Manual by Denis')->getTemplateId();
                Mage::log('Codigo do template: '.$template,null,'events.log');

                $sender  = array(
                'name' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()),
                'email' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                );

                Mage::log($sender,null,'events.log');

                $customerName = $order->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname() . " " . $order->getShippingAddress()->getLastname();
                $customerEmail = $order->getPayment()->getOrder()->getEmail();

                $vars = Array( 'order' => $order );

                $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); 

                $translate  = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
                Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                  ->sendTransactional($template, $sender, $customerEmail, $customerName, $vars, $storeId);
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::log('Order successfully sent',null,'events.log');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::log($e->getMessage(),null,'events.log');
            }
        } else {
            Mage::log('Order not found',null,'events.log');
        }
    }
}
```

Magento version: 1.5.1.0

Comment: Did you add the template to Admin -> Transactional Emails (id 16), since it doesn't seem like you have a default in your config.xml

Comment: Yes, I did it. The Transactional Email 16 exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
$customerEmail = $order->getPayment()->getOrder()->getEmail();
```

should probably be

```
$customerEmail = $order->getPayment()->getOrder()->getCustomerEmail();
```

You should pay attention to what the error message says and check the output of your variables.